# foundry forge vm.rollFork not working as expected

Tags: foundry, forge

I'm using vm.rollFork feature in foundry to get _token.totalSupply() at two different blocks but test failing because its returning same totalSupply number for two different blocks. I have checked and totalSupply number, if tested individually for these two blocks returns different number.

`forge test --match-contract rollForkTest  -vv  --fork-url https://rpc.ankr.com/eth`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import {Test, console2} from "forge-std/Test.sol";

interface ERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
}

contract rollForkTest is Test {
    ERC20 _token;

    function setUp() public {
        // _token = ERC20(0x06325440D014e39736583c165C2963BA99fAf14E);  //dai
        _token = ERC20(0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2); //weth
    }

    function testTokenSupply() public {
        vm.rollFork(17958426);

        uint256 prev = _token.totalSupply();
        console2.log("totalSupply prev ", prev);
        console2.log("block", block.number, "timestamp", block.timestamp);

        vm.rollFork(18074858);

        uint256 later = _token.totalSupply();
        console2.log("totalSupply later", later);
        console2.log("block", block.number, "timestamp", block.timestamp);

        assertNotEq(prev, later);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem recently also.

Selecting the first fork in setup and doing vm.rollFork in the test will give you the correct behavior but its a bit of a work around.